# Eloquent belongsTo relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Not sure why it's now working for me.

I have two tables

```
events
- id

selections
- id
- event_id
```

From my `Event` model I want to relationship selections

```
class Event extends Model
{
   ...
   public function selections()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(Selection::class, 'event_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

My problem is that `$event->selections` relationship is not working. Keep getting `null` back.

Comment: how are you retrieving the event?

Comment: to define a relationship we should place a method. `selections()` instead. hope that's just copy paste mistake.

Comment: @Serg just using a simple Event::find(1);

Comment: @SanzeebAryal Yes, it was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the database schema, it is hasMany relation instead.

```
public function selections()
   {
        return $this->hasMany(Selection::class, 'event_id', 'id');
   }
```

See [One to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in documentation.